# Silencing unnecessary capybara-webkit warnings

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

Any advice on silencing these capybara-webkit warnings?

> 2015-09-06 14:15:38.455 webkit_server[3700:6222738] Error loading
>   /Users/justin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web
>   Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib: 
>   dlopen(/Users/justin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web
>   Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib, 265): no suitable
>   image found.  Did find:   /Users/justin/Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web
>   Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib: mach-o, but wrong
>   architecture plugin,NP_Initialize start plugin,NP_Initialize end
>   plugin,NP_GetEntryPoints start Private_Initialize
>   plugin,NP_GetEntryPoints end 2015-09-06 14:15:38.463
>   webkit_server[3700:6222738] Error loading
>   /Users/justin/Library/Application
>   Support/Facebook/video/3.1.0.522/FacebookVideoCalling.webplugin/Contents/MacOS/FacebookVideoCalling:
>   dlopen(/Users/justin/Library/Application
>   Support/Facebook/video/3.1.0.522/FacebookVideoCalling.webplugin/Contents/MacOS/FacebookVideoCalling,
>   262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/justin/Library/Application
>   Support/Facebook/video/3.1.0.522/FacebookVideoCalling.webplugin/Contents/MacOS/FacebookVideoCalling:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture 2015-09-06 14:15:38.493
>   webkit_server[3700:6222738] Cannot find executable for CFBundle
>   0x7ffd14fcd260  (not loaded)
>   2015-09-06 14:15:38.495 webkit_server[3700:6222738] Error loading
>   /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime
>   Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: 
>   dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime
>   Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image
>   found.  Did find:     /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime
>   Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: mach-o, but wrong
>   architecture objc[3700]: Class AdobePDFProgressView is implemented in
>   both /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewer and
>   /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[3700]: Class
>   ObjCTimerObject is implemented in both /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewer and
>   /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[3700]: Class
>   MacCocoaSocketServerHelperRtc is implemented in both /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin and
>   /Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a snippet to prevent the warnings from showing up in the console:    https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/157.

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_unknown_urls  # <--- this configuration would be lost if you didn't use .merge below
end

class WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed
  IGNOREABLE = Regexp.new( [
    'CoreText performance',
    'userSpaceScaleFactor',
    'Internet Plug-Ins',
    'is implemented in bo'
  ].join('|') )

  def write(message)
    if message =~ IGNOREABLE
      0
    else
      puts(message)
      1
    end
  end
end

Capybara.register_driver :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed do |app|
  Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(
    app,
    Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(  # <------ maintain configuration set in Capybara::Webkit.configure block
      stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed.new
    )
  )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed
```

While this works to hide the messages, I feel the right way of fixing it would be to prevent loading the plugins from ever being loaded. But I haven't figured out how to do that with Capybara and webkit.